# Break não funciona no foreach

Tags: php, foreach, switch, break

eu tenho um foreach dentro de outro foreach que vai rodar por vários valores de um objeto em específico. Mas eu preciso parar os dois foreach's quando ele entrar dentro do if, porém o comando `break` não funciona por algum motivo, ele simplesmente continua rodando os dois foreach's. O código é mais ou menos assim:

```
foreach($conteudo["data"] as $oddss) {

    foreach($oddss["types"]["data"] as $oddss2) {
        if($oddss2["type"] == "1x2") {

            $bookmarker = $oddss["bookmaker_id"];

            foreach($oddss2["odds"]["data"] as $oli) {

                switch($oli["label"]) {
                    case 1:
                        $cotCasa = $oli["value"];
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        $cotFora = $oli["value"];
                        break;
                    case "X":
                        $cotEmp = $oli["value"];
                }

            }
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, tem `break` ali que se refere ao `switch`. No `} break;}` coloque `break 2;` veja se esse é o resultado desejado.

Comment: Era exatamente isso que eu precisava. Eu não sabia que existia esse break 2. Obrigado!

Comment: Pode ser qualquer número só não pode ser uma variável :)

Comment: Ta bem, valeu!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `break` está saindo do `switch` e não do `foreach`, mude ele para `if`/`elseif` que não precisa de `break` para sair e aí o `break` sairá do `foreach`. Ou use o [`break 2`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) para fazer duas saídas, uma do `switch` e outra do `foreach`.

Comment: Obrigado, isso que eu precisava!